# How can I troubleshoot javascript or http errors in wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: javascript, php, wkhtmltopdf

For a while now, I have used wkhtmltopdf for on-the-fly generation of pdf documents, and generally it is far ahead of the pack (compared with other tools available in php).

However, it is a HUGE PAIN to do even the most basic debugging of this process.
With your regular browser, one might `alert(var);` or `console.log(var);` and discover that "var" is `undefined`. Again, you can easily see a `404` or `500` http error somewhere in the browser console.

Take for instance this:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe http://localhost/mypage.html C:/temp/myfile.pdf
```

The pdf file does get created but is imperfect because certain aspects dependent on javscript or AJAX are missing.

With wkhtmltopdf, how best can I investigate these kinds of errors, if they exist in `mypage.html`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `--debug-javascript` command-line option. I tested it in Linux, but it's probably the same on Windows:

```
$ echo '<script>console.log("YAY!");</script>' > test.html
$ wkhtmltopdf --debug-javascript test.html test.pdf
Loading pages (1/6)
Warning: file:///tmp/test.html:1 YAY!
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

For 404 and 500 error, `wkhtmltopdf` should prints some stuff on the command line too, if I remember well.

Comment: Thanks @lorenzo-s: A bleak light at the end of the tunnel. When I run the command raw on the command line, I get something cryptic like so: `Warning: undefined:0 TypeError: 'null' is not an object`. Now, I'm actually calling wkhtmltopdf via php. Now, using `shell_exec()` and `exec()`, none of them gives any output in php! Could you possibly help..

Comment: `TypeError: 'null' is not an object`: probably you are trying to access a property on a null reference. Unfortunately it does not tell you where, so my best guess is to add random `console.log()`s and search for the line where it stops. Calling `wkhtmltopdf` from PHP does not change anything, you can't see output because it's on stderr, not stdout. I don't know how it works on Windows, but on Linux you must append ` 2>&1` to the command.

Comment: I stuck to the command line for the testing, and didn't bother with the PHP output issues. And yes, I was eventually able to track the offending script block using line-by-line `console.log()`. Indeed, the greatest thing I've learned today is that you can actually `console.log` with wkhtmltopdf! Thank you so much.

Comment: This flag (`--debug-javascript`) works on macOS as well, tested on wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you should just open the source page in your browser first. Your browser's debugger can trace the issues. Once you know the page is perfect, you can run it through wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Thanks @Ben for your input. The source page is indeed working perfectly, but not the PDF.

Comment: If elements of the page are being built up in javascript, it might be that wkhtmltopdf simple doesn't process it correctly internally. I would try to rebuild the page as much as possible in pure HTML/CSS if you can.

Comment: If that fails, you can always try TCPDF to get complete control over the outputted PDF. It gives you complete control, but comes at the price of a steep learning curve. It's not an option if you need something in a hurry.

Comment: Thanks again, @BenHiller. I was actually seriously contemplating abandoning all the AJAX for pure html/css as you advised (as if it was a piece of cake!) but it turned out there was a way, aided by Lorenzo's answer. I do appreciate your time.